# Need help spotting an error in my code regarding reading a matrix through a buffer

Tags: java, output

this is an homework question but I have been working at it for quite a while and I must be getting slightly blind so I would really appreciate help spotting an error.

```
public class Maze {

    int[][] grid;
    private final int TRIED = 2;
    private final int PATH = 3;

    public Maze(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String s;
        String [] aux= new String [2];
        int x=0; 

        aux=in.readLine().split("\\s*[, .]\\s*");
        int dimensao=Integer.parseInt(aux[0]);
        String [][] gridString= new String [dimensao][dimensao];
        grid= new int[dimensao][dimensao];

         while ((s=in.readLine())!=null){
            gridString [x]=s.split("\\s*[,.]\\s*");
            x++;
            System.out.println(s);
        }
         System.out.println();
        for (int i=0;i<gridString.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<gridString[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(gridString[i][j]+" ");
                switch (gridString[i][j]) {
                    case "true":
                        grid[i][j]=1;
                        break;
                    case "false":
                        grid[i][j]=0;
                        break;
                }
            }            
            System.out.println();
            }
        for (int i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<grid[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }           
    }
```

and in another class class I invoke it using this an input:

```
 5 

true, false, true, false, false 

true, false, true, true, true 

false, false, false, false, true

true, true, false, true, true

false, false, false, true, false
```

The goal is to convert into an integer matrix with "true" being represented by 1 and "false" being 0.
Things is my output is this

```
10100

10110

00000

11010

00010
```

And I just cant figure out what happened to the "true" values on tha last column.

Comment: Could the last column have a newline or something included in the true or false. The the string wouldn't match true or false and since, your switch doesn't have a default, it would just leave that grid entry blank (and probably defaulted to 0).

Comment: @MarkS. That's not possible because `\s` will also match new lines

Comment: what problem you are facing....i tried same code its working as expected..

Comment: check file that you are passing.....i think that some extra spaces are there at the end of each line...try removing those spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be the missing space in the second split  - maybe reading in as " true"